# How to set button as navigate to next question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I've created a quiz app, and the radio buttons are set to progress to the next question. How can I set it so the "Next question" button progresses to the next question instead and shows a message to the user below the answers if they have selected correctly or not?

I tried a function on the `<button className="next-question" onClick={() => nextQuestion()}>Next question</button>` that triggers the `setCounter` of `checkAnswer` function to progress to the next question,but it isn’t allowing only one radio button to be clicked at a time.

```
function App() {
  let [points, setPoints] = useState(null);
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(null);
  let [question, setQuestions] = useState();
  let [is_started, setStart] = useState(false);
  let [is_end, setEnd] = useState(false);

  function Answer(props) {
    return (
      <li aria-labelledby='answers-list'>
        <label><input type="radio" className="answer" data-correct={props.correct} onChange={props.checkAnswer}/>{props.answer}</label>
      </li>
    );
  }
  
  function Quiz(props) {
    return (
      <div className="quiz">
        <div className="question" role="h2">{props.question}</div>
        <ul className="answers">{props.children}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function checkAnswer(e) {
    if (e.target.dataset.correct === "true") {
      setPoints(points + 1);
    }

    let nextQuestion = counter + 1;
    if (counter < question.length - 1) {
      setCounter(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      setEnd(!is_end);
      setStart(!is_started);
      setCounter(0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Quiz">
      {!is_started ? (
      <div className="start-intro-wrapper">
        <h1 className="name">Quiz App</h1>
        <Starter start={start} />
      </div>
      ):(
        <div className="quick-wrapper">
          <Quiz question={question[counter].question}>
            {question[counter].answers.map((answer, index, arr) => {
              return (
                <Answer
                  key={index}
                  answer={answer.value}
                  checkAnswer={checkAnswer}
                  correct={answer.correct ? "true" : "false"}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Quiz>
          <button className="next-question">Next question</button>
        </div>)}
      {is_end && <div className="results-container"><ScoreMessage score={points} /></div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Current state in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gould-r1ucrb?file=/src/App.js)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one implementation of what you've specified

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  let [points, setPoints] = useState(null);
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(null);
  let [question, setQuestions] = useState();
  let [is_started, setStart] = useState(false);
  let [is_end, setEnd] = useState(false);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("./questions.json")
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        setQuestions(data);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  function Answer(props) {
    return (
      <li aria-labelledby="answers-list">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer_group"
            className="answer"
            value={props.answer}
          />
          {props.answer}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  }

  function Starter(props) {
    return (
      <button className="starter" onClick={props.start}>
        {is_end ? "Restart" : "Start"}
      </button>
    );
  }

  function Quiz(props) {
    return (
      <div className="quiz">
        <div className="quesiton" role="h2">
          {props.question}
        </div>
        <ul className="answers">{props.children}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function start() {
    setCounter(0);
    setPoints(0);
    setStart(!is_started);
    setEnd(false);
  }

  function displayCorrect(correct) {
    let correct_msg = correct ? "correct" : "incorrect";
    console.log("Answer was " + correct_msg);
  }

  function nextQuestion() {
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="answer_group"]:checked') == null) {
      alert("Must select an answer before proceeding to the next question");
      return;
    }
    let val = document.querySelector('input[name="answer_group"]:checked')
      .value;
    let answerObj = question[counter].answers.filter(
      (ans) => ans.value === val
    )[0];
    let updated_points = answerObj.correct ? points + 1 : points;
    console.log(updated_points);
    setPoints(updated_points);
    let nextQuestion = counter + 1;
    if (counter < question.length - 1) {
      setCounter(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      setEnd(!is_end);
      setStart(!is_started);
      setCounter(0);
    }
    displayCorrect(answerObj.correct);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Quiz">
      {!is_started ? (
        <div className="start-intro-wrapper">
          <h1 className="name">Quiz App</h1>
          <Starter start={start} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="quick-wrapper">
          <Quiz question={question[counter].question}>
            {question[counter].answers.map((answer, index, arr) => {
              return (
                <Answer
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  answer={answer.value}
                  correct={answer.correct}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Quiz>
          <button className="next-question" onClick={(e) => nextQuestion()}>
            Next question
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All the code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sun-bsbemr?file=/src/App.js:0-3129)

**Edit:** Included feedback as soon as a radio button is selected as OP commented.

```js
function Answer(props) {
    return (
      <li aria-labelledby="answers-list">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer_group"
            className="answer"
            value={props.answer}
            onChange={checkAnswer}
          />
          {props.answer}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  }

  function checkAnswer(e) {
    let val = e.target.value;
    let ans = question[counter].answers.filter((ans) => ans.value === val)[0];
    displayCorrect(ans.correct);
  }
```

Comment: This is closer to the correct logic, but need to show the “correct” or “incorrect” message after the radio button is selected, rather than after clicking the “next question” button.

Comment: The changes in the edit now provide feedback whenever a radio button is checked.

Comment: I see the update sends the "answer is correct" message to the console, but as per the question, how can I get it to render above the button, and then clear out when the next question button is clicked?